# Can Visio import C# code?

Tags: c#, events, uml, visio

is it possible to somehow import C# code into Microsoft Visio 2010 to generate UML Models?

The main problem is that I don't know how to model an interface which defines an event like below:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    bool Method();

    event EventHandler MyEvent;
}
```

So I thought it would be easiest if Visio is capable of importing my code, nevertheless if someone can explain to me how to model the interface described above I don't need to import anything.

Comment: I don't think there is, sorry!

Comment: @Mark Pattision: Is it possible to see what you edited that I may learn from my mistakes?

Comment: @b52 Yes, just click on [edited X mins ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11792177/revisions)...

Comment: Yes, just click on "4 minutes ago" where it says "edited 4 minutes ago", above my name (obviously the number of minutes will change by the time you read this...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Visio will do this.  However, [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html/) will.  You could do a free trial and see what it produces.  Also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51464/how-do-you-show-events-in-uml-class-diagrams) might help as it discusses how some others are modelling events in UML.